# Keep getting a redirect loop when connecting to a specific link on Flutter

Tags: android, http, flutter, redirect-loop

Whenever I try to connect to this specific website using Flutter/Dart I get a redirect loop error and it does not let me view to page. It works on other websites and I need to pull some data off this page for my app to function. I have no problem connecting in browser, nor using Java URLs in Android Studio.

I have tried using Flutter http plugin and Dart's HttpClient and neither have worked. I have tried using run and debug modes.

```dart
class Fetcher {
 void fetchData() async {
    print("starting");
    var response = await http.get("https://publix.org/");
    print(response.headers);
  }
}
```

I expect the page to load properly as it does in Java and web browser, however it goes into an infinite redirect loop.

E/flutter ( 8679): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: RedirectException: Redirect loop detected
E/flutter ( 8679): #0      Fetcher.fetchData (package:publix_schedule/fetcher.dart:10:5)
E/flutter ( 8679): 
E/flutter ( 8679): #1      DrawerWidget.build. (package:publix_schedule/main.dart:38:27)
E/flutter ( 8679): #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:511:14)
E/flutter ( 8679): #3      _InkResponseState.build. (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:566:30)
E/flutter ( 8679): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:166:24)
E/flutter ( 8679): #5      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:240:9)
E/flutter ( 8679): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:211:7)
E/flutter ( 8679): #7      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter ( 8679): #8      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:225:20)
E/flutter ( 8679): #9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:199:22)
E/flutter ( 8679): #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 8679): #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter ( 8679): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter ( 8679): #13     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
E/flutter ( 8679): #14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter ( 8679): #15     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
E/flutter ( 8679): #16     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:233:10)
E/flutter ( 8679): #17     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:5)

Comment: Was anything `print`'d?

Comment: At the browser, I'm getting an Access Denied on https://publix.org/

Comment: @JulienLachal Only the first message before I get the page

Comment: @JulioHenriqueBitencourt Very odd, I have no trouble connecting with my browser.